# How do I manually set the total row count for the pagination for the Material-UI Data Grid?

Tags: html-table, material-ui, pagination, datagrid

I am overriding the onClick for the previous/next for the pagination for my DataGrid table with `onPageChange` and `onPageSizeChange`. This is because I am doing an api call each next/prev page click to get the next/prev page data. Thus I have to manually set the total page count (ex: 1-5 of 150, I'd want to set manually the 150).

`rowCount` requires me to turn off pagination so I cannot use this.